# networkx graph combinations with some requirement

Tags: python, combinations, networkx

I want to make a combinations of NetworkX graph (undirected).

Known conditions:

- Number of nodes.
- Number of neighbors of each nodes.

Constraints:

- Can't be isomorphic.
- All nodes must be connected.
- No any triangles.

I'm used `itertools.combinations` function try to generate all the list of combinations first, then test the constraints of graph, but when number of nodes comes to bigger then 8, that is too slow.

Is there any faster functional ways to do this?

Comment: Your question is more about the algorithm for the task than a Stack Overflow programming question. I suggest a different Stack Exchange, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581780/number-of-r-regular-triangle-free-graphs-of-order-100?rq=1

Comment: Do you want **all** graphs that satisfy your requirements, or just **one or more** graphs that satisfy your requirements? In the latter case, I think you should be able to come up with a rewiring function that does the job.

Comment: I need all. But in so many results that I generated by combinations function, there is less than a quarter of results can meet my requirement. Maybe some test function can be able to set in advance, so it can be more efficiently.